# Warning: PDOStatement::bindValue(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make a `query` function as follow :

```
public function Query( $sql, $params = array() ) {
        $this->error = false;

        if ( $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare( $sql ) ) {
            for ( $i = 0, $size = count( $params ); $i < $size; $i ++ ) {
                echo $i;
                $this->query->bindValue( $i, $params[ $i ] );
            }

            if ( $this->query->execute() ) {
                echo 'suc';
            }
        }
    }
```

and call it like this :

```
$mysql->Query( "SELECT * FROM `client_info` WHERE `name` = ? AND `password`= ?", array(
    'test',
    'test'
) );
```

and the result is :

```
Warning: PDOStatement::bindValue(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

I have no clue what's wrong here , everything supposed to be fine and it should work!!

Comment: Try with this for loop: `for ( $i = 1, $size = count( $params ); $i <= $size; $i ++ ) {
                echo $i;
                $this->query->bindValue( $i, $params[ $i-1 ] );
            }` Does this do the trick for you?

Comment: I fixed it by doing `bindValue( $i + 1, $params[ $i ] );` without change anything in the loop , same thing tho!

Comment: You're right! Even better solution nice :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 $i = 0
```

And

> Warning: PDOStatement::bindValue(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based

Compare those two things, you will notice that your `$i` has to start at 1, not 0.

This can also be confirmed from the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

**parameter**

> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. ***For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter.***

Comment: Very nice explanation :D If you want you can copy the for loop how it should be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124598/warning-pdostatementbindvalue-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-c#comment44622637_28124598 With starting the loop at 1 and with the array access just subtract 1. (BTW: You have 1 space there `$i = 0`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this issue when you do something as simple as having a messed up abstraction function and you end up passing an array to the bindValue() when it should be a string, as in:

```
$a = array(':slug','mickey1');
$st = $PDO->prepare($sSQL);
$st->bindValue(':slug',$a); // the bug!
```

In my case, I should have made `$a` as `array(':slug' => 'mickey1')` and should have iterated my array so that I could `bindValue()` by each string key of the associative array.